# What rise time should pulse have to have desired pulse width

Tags: pulse, high-frequency, rise-time

I have a question regarding my high speed laser driver. I want to have 10ns width pulse. What rise/fall time I would need to have that I can say I still have 10ns pulse. Is there any percentage   that system should be turned on in one time unit?

Comment: How do you define a "pulse"? How do you define the width of a "pulse"? How do you define "rise time" and "fall time"? Is this an optical pulse or an electrical pulse? Your question can not be answered properly without this information.

Comment: I define pulse as electrical, one time square wave. Rise time is time required for rising edge of pulse to go from 10% to 90% of amplitude. Fall is time required for falling edge of pulse to go from 90% to 10% of amplitude.

Comment: 5 ns rise and 5 ns fall will be good enough to meet some requirements. You need to decide what your pulse shape requirements are to suit what you use it for.

Comment: You haven't given us your definition of "pulse width". At what voltage levels do you measure the width of the pulse?

Comment: It's up to what you want to deal with. I think 1/3 rise, 1/3 level and 1/3 fall is the bare minimum I like. It barely looks like a pulse then and you spend more time in transition than level. 1/4, 1/2, 1/4 might be preferred so at least half the time isn't spent transitioning but that's borderline too if you're after a square or rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to you to define.

What are you going to use the pulse for?

Once you know the purpose of the pulse, the requirements should be apparent.

A rule of thumb knowing nothing about the application might say that the 10%-90% risetimes should be less than 10% of the pulse width.

But once you know whether the system starts to react at the 10% amplitude level, or 50% or the 90% level, for ***your particular application***, you might alter that view.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a universally accepted definition of "rise time" (or "pulse width").  So ultimately the laser pulse *shape* needs to be acceptable to whoever you're designing the laser *for*.

Probably-generally-acceptable definitions for rise- and fall-times would be, for example, the time it takes to get from 10% of full scale to 90% or back -- or from 20% to 80% or back.  "Pulse width" might be the time the pulse spends above 50%.  But this all depends on your application, and what it means to you.